# Meaning of abs. value of a sigma field?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-value

In a hand out I saw the a notation which looks to be the absolute value of a sigma field F, |F|. I googled it but I could not really find what it means and the notation confuses me. Anyone that might enlighten me of the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $|F|$ refers to the cardinality of the field. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality.

Comment: Thanks. I should have found that... sorry